# How to load Excel file data into Snowflake table

Tags: excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, xls

There is a use case to load Excel file (.xls, .xlsx) into Snowflake.

Using SnowSQL PUT command I'm able to load the file to Stage (User Stage) and it works fine till this point. Next step is to load from User Stage to Snowflake Table using COPY INTO command. Issue is that there is no FILE_FORMAT available in Snowflake to specify XLS type data.

I don't want to convert XLS in CSV format which is available option for FILE_FORMAT type.
Any clue how this can be done without modifying source Excel file?

Comment: An Excel file can be easily transformed into CSV by using Excel's: **File->Save As->File Format**. But yes, that means from the source file. I don't think it's possible to be done afterwards inside Snowflake. You can also use for example Python to read an xls file into a dataframe and load that into Snowflake, but again it's from the source.

Comment: HI as mentioned by Sergiu one option is to sakve it as a CSV and load in to Snowflake, any reason why you don't want to  convert to CSV ?

Comment: @hkandpal: There are multiple sheets within an excel file and around 500+ files need to be uploaded to Snowflake. It is very manual and error prone process to convert each of them in csv. Further there are unicode characters in Excel and also there is a risk to loose special characters like En-Dash during conversion. Validating so many files after conversion is a huge task again.

Comment: I talked to Snowflake support, seems they are all Mac/Linux lovers and not knee to support anything from Windows system, e.g. .NET, Office suit.  They have been telling us these are on their roadmap for three years and yet there is nothing support Microsoft stuff is appearing. If you are a python, Mac user, Snowflake has a lot of support.  MS, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake doesn't support loading data directly from Excel files as of this date. You have to convert the source file to a supported format.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree that converting data to CSV is error prone. While not "native" to the Snowflake options, Snowflake does have a python connector and there are a number of python excel libraries. Here's a Snowflake reference on this: [python-connector-pandas](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html)  And one library example: [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Given your subsequent comments about multiple sheets within the excel workbooks and the number of files, I think a programmatic solution is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

1. convert your file to CSV
   2.put your file into data-lake or s3bucket
2. create file format
3. load your csv file using copy command https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Option 2:

1. convert excel to csv.
2. go to UI create file format
   [image: fileformat]
3. click on the the table-->load table
   [image: load table]
4. select file
   [image: Select picture from computer]
5. choose file format
   [image: Choose newly created file format]
6. Load option
   [image: Choose your best options]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to process your excel file using Python, then load the data into Snowflake. Please use the code below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
snowflake_username = 'username'
snowflake_password = 'password'
snowflake_account = 'accoutname'
snowflake_warehouse = 'warehouse'
snowflake_database = 'database'
snowflake_schema = 'public'

engine = create_engine(
'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{db}/{schema}?warehouse= 
    {warehouse}'.format(
     user=snowflake_username,
     password=snowflake_password,
     account=snowflake_account,
     db=snowflake_database,
     schema=snowflake_schema,
     warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,
    ),echo_pool=True, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20
)

try:
 connection = engine.connect()

 df_sensor.columns = map(str.upper, df_sensor.columns)
 df_sensor.to_sql('tb_equipments'.lower(), con=connection, 
 schema='public', index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=16000)
 results = connection.execute('select count(1) from 
 tb_equipments').fetchone()

print('\nTotal de linhas inseridas: ',results[0], '\n')
```

finally:
connection.close()
engine.dispose()

Comment: Thanks Jayron. I can see code to connect to Snowflake but can't find source excel file connection. Do you have code to connect to excel file? how to specify file format in Python?

Comment: @MayankJha I did simple read using pandas read_excel, like this:
df =  pd.read_excel(s3.open(f'{s3_bucket}/business_cases/{organization_id}/INPUTS/raw/{filename}',index_col=None, engine='openpyxl', skiprows=0, header=2, date_parser=pd.datetime))
||||
For more information please look at the link below:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but here it is. I have a Power Automate Desktop flow that leverages Snowsql to automatically load csv files to Snowflake.

For large files select split file by nn M rows to leverage fast load of large volumes.
The app does not detect datatypes, it load the data as string, you should have snowflake or DBT setup to process the data into your production stuff.

Check out
https://github.com/paddelia1/csvToSnowflake
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtYvV.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the other users have suggested, decoupling the worksheets and converting each sheet to CSVs might be the most guaranteed option for your use case.

Alternatively, you can use pre-built transformation services for the loading - the transformation services/tools that integrate tightly with snowflake.

The advantage is that some of these tools offer a way to immediately work on your dataset upon extraction, before pushing it back into your snowflake DW.

That way you get to review your extracts on the fly.

I work with a team trying to cater to this particular pain point. We currently support easy loading of JSON,CSV and might ramp up to supporting excel as well in the near future.

If you're interested, you could try out [the CSV feature here](https://www.datameer.com/upload-csv-to-snowflake/), if it helps.

Comment: I notice that you've posted several answers promoting datameer. While you have disclosed affiliation, please make sure to not post too many answers promoting a product you're affiliated with, as that can be considered spam (when the question doesn't explicitly mention the product). Promoting a product in a small percentage of your answers is fine.