# Is there any way to load the excel fiel from the blob storage to snowflake without using the ADF?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, snowflake-schema

Basically, I have  the xlsx file in the azure blob container, I tried to use the ADF but it is taking more time to load the data to the snowflake table. even for the small file it is taking 30 odd secs.

I tried a couple of other alternatives like;

1. Copy into the command: it is not supporting the xlsx format
2. Snowpark: same issue as number 1

It would be great for me to know if there are any alternatives for this issue.

Comment: Convert the XLSX file into CSV, then split the file based on some criteria. use snowflake PUT to parallely load the file into snowflake stage

Comment: @RajibDeb, my excel file is in the cloud i.e. Azure Blob Container, So is it possible to use the put command while loading the data from the cloud?

Comment: No, it will work with local storage on a machine, will not work on object store. If it is on Azure, have u tried creating a file format and then an external stage.

Comment: @RajibDeb Snowflake doesn't support the XLSX file format for the external stage, do you see any alternatives to mimic the xlsx format using CSV?

Answer (score 0):

AS per this [Snowflake Document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format), It currently does not enable importing data straight from Excel files. You must change the source file's format like `CSV`.

**If you are not using ADF** you need to first convert that excel files into a **`CSV`** file. since Azure Blob Storage is just object storage which treats all formats in the same way. Therefore, you must download your Excel blob to your local machine and convert it to CSV, then upload it back to Azure Blob Storage.

For that you can use:

- Azure functions that read excel file from blob storage convert it into CSV and load it in blob storage again.
- Azure blob sdk python to convert the `Excel` to `CSV` using python pandas libraries and load it to blob storage again.
- Python application that loads the Excel file into a Panda dataframe and then loads that dataframe to Snowflake.

Also see, similar question - [How to load Excel file data into Snowflake table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184641/how-to-load-excel-file-data-into-snowflake-table)